# Self is not defined

Tags: python

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.61\scripts\addons\ArenWorldExporter.py", line 73, in execute
    _mkdir(self.filepath[:-4] + "\\models\\")
  File "V:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.61\scripts\addons\ArenWorldExporter.py", line 73, in _mkdir
    _mkdir(self.filepath[:-4] + "\\models\\")
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/B2U0DAr8

All the spacing is set to 4 spaces, no tabs (not even sure if the python editor supports tabs)

Why is it saying that self is not defined? As it clearly is in the function.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your indentation. Try looking at the file in a couple of different editors. Either `_mkdir` is part of the class, as the indentation shows, in which case you need to call it `self._mkdir`, or it isn't, and your indentation is wrong. If `execute` isn't part of the class, which would be what would give you that error, then your indentation is wrong again.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but lines 20,25,34... --- `return{....}` doesn't seem like valid python syntax to me...

Comment: It has to be the indentation. `execute` is not in your stack trace

Comment: @mgilson: those are set literals.  Should work in py >= 2.7.

Comment: @DSM Good to know, thanks.  I'm using py 2.6 which is why it didn't fly when I tried it.  (for me, the code didn't pass the syntax parsing)

Comment: The returns are used in blender which is what this is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
 _mkdir(self.filepath[:-4] + "\\models\\")
```

should be:

```
 self._mkdir(self.filepath[:-4] + "\\models\\")
```

If you want to see a `self` in `_mkdir()`, it must be called on an instance.